# How do I check if solr is running or no using python?

Tags: python, search, solr, search-engine, pysolr

I am using pysolr library and I want to check if solr is running or no
and to switch between solr and other search engine. 
I found similar question and I tried many suggestions and didn't work.
[How to know whether solr server is running or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293498/how-to-know-whether-solr-server-is-running-or-not)
[How do i check cassandra and solr is up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669204/how-do-i-check-cassandra-and-solr-is-up)
[Python code to check if service is running or not.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579170/python-code-to-check-if-service-is-running-or-not)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744747/how-to-find-whether-solr-server-is-running-or-not

Comment: You'll have to explain why either of those examples didn't work - but in your case - how about just try to make the query to Solr with a low timeout, and if no answer arrives within 1 - 2s, mark Solr as down and query the other search service. Each 15m reset the mark and retry the connection.

Comment: I tried that : pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/', timeout=10) and I tried :solr=pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/catalogue',timeout=10)
solr.ping() it shows an error : AttributeError: 'Solr' object has no attribute 'ping'

Comment: The `ping` method [was added in pysolr 3.9.0](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr/releases/tag/v3.9.0). Upgrade your pysolr dependency.

Answer (score 2):

A clean way is using [pysolr](https://pypi.org/project/pysolr/)

```
import pysolr

# Create a client instance. The timeout and authentication options are not required.
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/')

# Do a health check.
ping = solr.ping()
resp = json.loads(ping)

if resp.get('status') == 'OK':
   print('success')
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: 'Solr' object has no attribute 'ping'. This seems to be an issue according to this: https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr/issues/260. Has this issue been resolved? My version of pysolr is 3.8.1

Comment: This issue is fixed in version 3.9.0

Answer (score 0):

if the code below error(connection refused), solr is not working.
`gettingstarted` is an example collective name in the link.

```
from urllib.request import *
connection = urlopen('http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?q=mebus&wt=python')
response = eval(connection.read())
```